# create apk file from eclipse with text files folder

Tags: android, file, apk

i have create an .apk file in order to install it on my android device. is it possible with this .apk file to include a folder with text files and save them in the memory card?
it will install the application on the device and then it will copy the folder to the memory card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `asset/` ?

The `assets/` folder in apk is intended to store any extra user files in any formats. They will be included to apk automatically on compilation stage and can be accessed from the app using `getAssets()` function. For example:

```
   final InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("some_file.xml")
```

Comment: ok i will try to use it. but my questions are, 1)does it read the file fast enough? at the moment am using bufferedReaded. is it working such efficient or less?    2) also if i use it just add the code the you told me and with the export will create automaticaly the files in .apk ? 3) also do i have th ability when the application is working to deletes some of the files create new files or edit them?

Comment: Ans:1 - Yes, its work efficiently. As it is in application package itself.

Comment: Ans:2 - Android application package always contains asset directory within its package structure so you have to just copy your files in asset directory then when you build apk file it always contain asset directory with your files. You don't need to export it.

Comment: Ans: 3 - No, As android application package (.apk) file is read only. So you can't write or delete files from it at runtime, for this you have to first copies your all files from asset directory to internal storage package directory (/data/data/<package_name>/files) an use from it.